# listview elements behavior

Tags: android, android-listview

why when i write adapter listview, like below, listview elements random change positin? Sorry, for my awful English.

```
private class Adapt2 extends ArrayAdapter {
            ArrayList<String> jsonBanks;
            public Adapt2(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List objects) {
                    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
                    jsonBanks = new ArrayList<String>();
                    jsonBanks.addAll((ArrayList<String>)objects);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    if(convertView==null){
                            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            convertView= vi.inflate(R.layout.main_item, parent,false);

                            TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
                             tv.setText(jsonBanks.get(position));

                    }

                    return convertView;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Its because you don't follow the view holder approach for your listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your convertview is being re-used.
try this

```
if(convertView==null){
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView= vi.inflate(R.layout.main_item, parent,false);
}
TextView tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
tv.setText(jsonBanks.get(position));

return convertView;
```

watch this for more more details on what is happening

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: "convertview is being re-used", elements change position?

Comment: its not that they change position. Its that their visual representation is being reused since your code is saying it to do so by not doing anything when convertview is not null. This might give effect similar to "elements change position" ... which is my guess